# Recode numeric variables

Tags: dplyr, multiple-columns, recode

I've searched several help-pages and already answered questions but still get an error message when I try to recode multiple columns.

Example dataset:

```
test <- tibble (
  a_test = c(7,6,5,4),
  b_test = c(7,7,5,3),
  c_test = c(7,3,7,5),
  d_test = c(7,7,7,7)
)

test %>%
  mutate(across(vars(contains('test')), recode, "1" = "7", "2" = "6", "3" = "5", "4" = "4", "5" = "3", "6" = "2", "7" = "1")
```

Once I run this code, I get the following error message:

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `quosures`.
i It must be numeric or character.

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide your data using `dput(dataset)`? Also please be aware that [`mutate_at` has been superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html).

Comment: I've changed my question and the code, hope this clarifies my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `vars` argument, add a tilde (`~`), and begin your `recode` statement with `.x`.

On 1/25/23, I updated my answer to include a full reprex with my R version and `dplyr` package version. I also added the `as.numeric()` wrapper to ensure that the recoded values stay numeric after recoding.

```
library(dplyr)
R.version$version.string
#> [1] "R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)"
packageVersion("dplyr")
#> [1] '1.0.10'

test <- tibble(
  a_test = c(7,6,5,4),
  b_test = c(7,7,5,3),
  c_test = c(7,3,7,5),
  d_test = c(7,7,7,7)
)
sapply(test, class)
#>    a_test    b_test    c_test    d_test 
#> "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"

test2 <- test %>%
  mutate(across(contains("test"), ~
                  as.numeric(recode(.x, "1" = "7", "2" = "6", "3" = "5", "4" = "4", "5" = "3", "6" = "2", "7" = "1"))))
                
head(test2)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   a_test b_test c_test d_test
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      1      1      1      1
#> 2      2      1      5      1
#> 3      3      3      1      1
#> 4      4      5      3      1
sapply(test2, class)
#>    a_test    b_test    c_test    d_test 
#> "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```